# Remove existing WHERE clauses from $collection->getSelect()

Tags: magento-1.8, collection, query

I am trying to modify the Lifetime Sales figure on the admin landing page to include *pending_payment* orders. I have set up a module as follows:

```
class Steamdesk_Dashboard_Block_Dashboard_Sales extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Sales
```

And I have the following to set a suitable `WHERE` clause in the SQL for the collection:

```
$collection->getSelect()->where('main_table.state NOT IN (?)', array(
        Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CLOSED,
        Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED
    )
);
```

However there are already two elements in the `WHERE` clause array which will cause the above to be ignored, which I can see if I check `$collection->getSelect()` as follows:

```
[where] => Array
(
    [0] => (main_table.status NOT IN('canceled'))
    [1] => AND (main_table.state NOT IN('new', 'pending_payment'))
)
```

I know all this code is being run, but my question is how can I clear the existing attributes in the collection's generated SQL query?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply add `$collection->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);` to your code above your Query.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! Sorry I can't upvote but once I get a few more rep I'll be sure to come back :)